# Create event in symfony2 to render a twig file

Tags: php, symfony, events, twig

I'm new to symfony2 and I'm looking for solution to create an event that render a twig file.

Assume we have a base template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    {% block meta %}{% endblock %}
    <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body data-cachetime="{{ cacheTimeStamp() }}">
    {% block header %}{% endblock %}
    <div id="content">
        <div class="container">
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% block footer %}{% endblock %}
    {% block version %}{% endblock %}
    {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    {% block trackers %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I've a "version" block. I've created an VersionBundle which read the version from a file. The version twig template

```
{% block version %}
    <div id="version"><p>Version: {{ versionString() }}</p></div>
{% endblock %}
```

calls an "ViewHelper" (i came from Zend ;-)) which calls the function from VersionBundle. But now the tricky part:
The VerionBundle is only registered for 'dev' and 'test' Environment in the AppKernel.
Thats why i create the 'version' block instead of calling the ViewHelper directly in the base twig file.

But i don't know how to create an event to render the version twig template first so the data will passed to the base twig.

Comment: I don't understand why do you call it 'event'. Why don't you just add this div block with version info into your base template? What exactly do you need?

Comment: I don't want to ask for an environment in the base template and decide if i render the version block or not...
In "online" im not registering the bundle so versionString() is not available... that's why I'm using the version block... i want to avoid errors/warnings
Zend has the same functionallity called placeholder...

Answer (score 0):

I would maybe change the way you try to do it, using more Symfony features and avoiding defining Zend like "helpers". It's a good rule of thumb to keep Twig as minimal as it can be, just rendering view from data the templates receive.

First, define the `version` variable in `parameters_dev.yml` and `parameters_test.yml` files (in `app/config`). Example:

```
parameters:
    version: 32
```

Define it as `version: ~` in `parameters.yml`.

Make this variable available in all Twig templates in the `app/config/config.yml` file:

```
twig:
    globals:
        version: %version%
```

Then, in your `version` block definition, do the following:

```
{% block version %}
    {% if version is not null %}
        <div id="version"><p>Version: {{ version }}</p></div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That looks quite simple (what is good). There is only one problem, it's not portable. If i use this in my other projects i have to paste all the time (ok, it's not much) code block to every project.

Comment: Do you mean in a totally different project? (not the same Symfony instance, not the same Symfony app and bundles then)